# Junit IllegalStateException BeanCreationException with @Lob annotation

Tags: java, jpa, spring-boot, junit, lob

In my database, I changed a column from "varchar" to "text". In my class, I added the annotation "@Lob":

```
@Lob
@Column(name = "detail_produit")
private String detailProduit;
```

When I launch my web service, with data as below in my field, it works very well.

```
"detailProduit": "montre homme avec cadrant en morceaux \n montre homme avec cadrant en morceaux \n montre homme avec cadrant en morceaux \n montre homme avec cadrant en morceaux \n montre homme avec cadrant en morceaux \n montre homme avec cadrant en morceaux \n montre homme avec cadrant en morceaux \nmontre homme avec cadrant en morceaux \nmontre homme avec cadrant en morceaux \nmontre homme avec cadrant en morceaux \nmontre homme avec cadrant en morceaux \nmontre homme avec cadrant en morceaux \nmontre homme avec cadrant en morceaux",
```

My problem is all unit tests were failed, they are all failing with the following error since I added the annotation "@Lob":

```
fr.societe.appli.repository.CustomAuditEventRepositoryIntTest > 
    testAddEventWithNullData FAILED
        java.lang.IllegalStateException
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
            Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException
                Caused by:   org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException
```

I do not understand how to solve this error, do you have an idea? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Specify columnDefinition

```
 @Column(name = "detail_produit", columnDefinition="TEXT")
```

Comment: result is the same

Comment: Try @Indexed on the top of the class and create new database.

Comment: I understand my error.. I have modify directly in database but not in liquibase file..